# How to get the second column from command output?

Tags: awk

My command's output is something like:

```
                                   N O D E   O U T P U T

THE FOLLOWING TABLE IS PRINTED FOR NODES BELONGING TO NODE SET NSET_OUTPUT

   NODE FOOT-   NT11     
        NOTE

      3       20.00     
     11       20.00     
   1003       23.75     
   1011       23.75     
   2003       27.52     
   2011       27.52     
   3003       31.30     
   3011       31.30     
   4003       35.08     
   4011       35.08     
   5003       38.87     
   5011       38.87     
   6003       42.67     
   6011       42.67     
   7003       46.48     
   7011       46.48     
   8003       50.29     
   8011       50.29     
   9003       54.12     
   9011       54.12     
  10003       57.95     
  10011       57.95     
  11003       61.79     
  11011       61.79     
  12003       65.64     
  12011       65.64     
  13003       69.50     
  13011       69.50     
  14003       73.37     
  14011       73.37     
  15003       77.25     
  15011       77.25     
  16003       81.14
```

The first column is always a number,My purpose is to get the second column only, like:

```
20.00
20.00
23.75
23.75
27.52
27.52
31.30
31.30
.
.
```

I intended to use

```
# gawk -f nset_output.awk electric_thermal.dat
BEGIN{
}
{
               if($12~/NSET_OUTPUT/ ){
                   for(i=1;i <= 5; i++){
                       getline
                   }
                   x=$2

        print x >"nset_output.dat"

    }       

}
```

to accomplish this.but,the output is messed up: (only one value 20.00)
20.00

So,How do I get the second column's value? (in my case I have 405 rows corresponding 405 values with 1 column)

Comment: If the header is fixed-length, you could remove it with just `tail`, and then `awk` for the other column. I'd suggest taking some care in indenting code, the snippet in the question is quite hard to interpret since the indentation and the braces do not match.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming it's enough to check for a digit in the first column:

```
awk '$1 ~ /[0-9]/ { print $2 }' data.in >data.out
```

To ensure that this only gets applied to lines after the `NSET_OUTPUT` line, you could do something like the following:

```
sed '1,/NSET_OUTPUT/d' data.in | awk '$1 ~ /[0-9]/ { print $2 }' >data.out
```

This will delete lines before `NSET_OUTPUT` and send the rest to the `awk` script.

---

Your script will only output one number since it, *for every line of input*, will look for `NSET_OUTPUT`, and if found, skip five lines before fetching the number from the second column.

The following is a fixed version of *your* script:

```
BEGIN { print_values = 0 }

$12 ~ /NSET_OUTPUT/ {
    for (i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
        getline;
    }

    print_values = 1;
}

print_values == 1 {
    x = $2;
    print x >"nset_output.dat"
}
```

Comment: Keeping in mind that the command output has a header(see the question revision) which can contain stuff like `3G` your regex need to be stricter to filter such values

Comment: @sjsam Not _quite_ sure I see that myself (looking through the revisions), but I've updated the answer nonetheless (in a way that makes it different from yours and Stephen's).

Answer (score 0):

We can test to see if the first field starts with a number and just print the second

```
awk '$1 ~ /^[0-9][0-9]*$/ { print $2}' electric_thermal.dat > nset_output.dat
```

This matches your source file and returns

```
20.00
20.00
23.75
23.75
27.52
27.52
31.30
31.30
....
```

Comment: Why not `[0-9]+`  coz  `first column is always a number` ? Also clearly the input comes from a command, so it should be piped

Comment: Not all versions of `awk` support the `+` syntax.  The question said that data came from `electric_thermal.dat`

Comment: Hmm,,, I overlooked the comment in the script.  Thanks. Regarding `+`  I never had a problem using with them with `gnu/non-gnu awks` What version did you mean?

Comment: Old old systems :-)

Answer (score 0):

`awk` is your friend:

```
awk '$1 ~ /^[[:digit:]]+$/{print $2}' electric_thermal.dat >outfile
```

should do it

Answer (score 0):

Command

```
 awk '$1 ~ /^[0-9]*$/{print $2}' file name


output
20.00
20.00
23.75
23.75
27.52
27.52
31.30
31.30
35.08
35.08
38.87
38.87
42.67
42.67
46.48
46.48
50.29
50.29
54.12
54.12
57.95
57.95
61.79
61.79
65.64
65.64
69.50
69.50
73.37
73.37
77.25
77.25
81.14
```

Answer (score -1):

If the above 7 lines are persistent after executing the command every time, use:

```
yourcommand | sed 1,7d | awk '{print $2}'
```

`sed 1,7d` will simply hide the first 7 lines, which you don't require. `awk` will sort out the exact content you are actually looking for...

```
cat yourcommand_out | sed 1,7d | awk '{print $2}'
20.00
20.00
23.75
23.75
27.52
27.52
31.30
31.30
35.08
35.08
38.87
38.87
42.67
42.67
46.48
46.48
50.29
50.29
54.12
54.12
57.95
57.95
61.79
61.79
65.64
65.64
69.50
69.50
73.37
73.37
77.25
77.25
81.14
```

Comment: Downvote: Useless [\[ use of cat \]](http://porkmail.org/era/unix/award.html#catl), and the solution doesn't satisfy the requirements. Also please format the code.

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```
awk '/^[ ]*[[:digit:]]/ {print $2}' inputFile
```

Comment: Please learn to use code blocks.